# Auto Sort UICollectionViewCell based on parameter in JSON swift

Tags: ios, json, sorting, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with cells populated from JSON response data. Currently the cells populate by category and everything runs smoothly.

My issue is that the cells are sorted alphabetically which is how they are sorted in the JSON file but I would like to have them sorted by a "Likes Count" parameter that every category contains.

So far I have found how to enable a user drag and re-arrange the cells but I would like to implement an "Auto-Sort" based on the number of "likes" each category in descending order.

I appreciate any help.

EDIT - Using Alamofire for the API call and Swiftyjson to parse.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "mydomain").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {

                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar.arrayObject {

                    self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]


                }

                if self.arrRes.count > 0 {

                   self.collectionView.reloadData()


                }
            }
        }
```

Setting up the label for the cells

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
        var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]

        cell.catLabel.text = dict["name"] as? String
        let likes = dict["likes count"] as? Int
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Show us your response/model class and code you have used to make api call.

Comment: Sort the dataSource and reloadData (if needed).

Comment: I've updated my question to include code that I'm using. I can get as far as returning the array of counts with Swiftyjson, I'm just not sure how I would use that information for sorting purposes. I'm still a newbie with this so apologies if this is too simple a request.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is an array of dictionaries and "likes" count is a key-value pair in the dictionary, you can sort them using

`array.sortInPlace({$0.likes > $1.likes})`

Answer (score 0):

> yourArray = JSON response data to get array;

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"likes" ascending:NO]]];
```

& then apply to your `UICollectionView` datasource in sorted array
& after reload your `UICollectionView`